# Why do think that moving images are different than still images when there's no such thing as a real moving image?

Tags: terminology

Why do people think that moving images is different than still images when there's no real moving images, the term ''moving images'' refers to the optical illusion where your brain thinks the images are moving when it's not, they're just still images displayed in quick succession, movies and television are technically still image media, every media are made out of still images like drawings, paintings and photographs, is there a reason behind this confusion?

Comment: Is it a confusion? Or a marketing statement?

 • Is there no difference? When you ask for a video, and you receive only one photo, is it the same?

 • Are every moving image made by still images? Are installations in a museum, images or not? Probably not, but when you see it, are they?

 • Is an SVG animation, where you define trajectory etc., not moving? 

 • Is an image in our brains moving? O just a series of still-retina-cell impulses?

 • Where do you draw the line?

 • Is this a philosophical question?

Comment: • Is time quantized? Is the plank time series of still-reality-existence periods?

• Is this a quantum-string theory question?

Comment: You seem to understand the distinction and the difference between a still image and a moving picture. So what is your actual question? "How did the name moving picture come to be when it isn't moving?" (Etymology) "What is the nature of movement that comes into a series of images when the persistence of vision threshold is met?" (Philosophy) "Why do people see movement where none exists?" (Neuroscience and psychology). Based on your responses, it sounds like the question you are asking is "Why are you all such idiots, don't you know that pictures can't move? I'm smarter than you."

Comment: All moving images are made out of still images, installations in museums are images, and no, this isn't a philosophical question.

Comment: I agree with the other community members that it's unclear what kind of answer you want to this question, perhaps beyond "yes, you're right" (which is honestly not a very interesting answer). Could you please try to clarify what you think would make a good answer to this question?

Comment: I'm closing this question as opinion-based, because it's clear this question is seeking to argue a perceptual and philosophical position.

Answer (score 2):

Moving images (or the much [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moving%20picture%2Cmoving%20image%2Cmovies%2Cmovie&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=0) terms moving pictures in the late 19th and early 20th centuries and movie in the mid 20th to today) are substantively different than still images in much the same way that a novel is different than a sentence. It is true that there is little difference in substance between a single frame of a motion picture and a photograph, but the sequence does create a largely different experience.

As far as motion picture being a common term, it comes down to marketing. At one point in time this was a novelty that most people had never heard of, let alone had the knowledge to fully grasp. It was usually (though not always) something you had to pay to see.

How many people will pay to come into a dark tent to see "a sequence of still images displayed at sufficient speed that your brain's automatic persistence of vision filtering will interpret it as motion"?

A picture was a well known thing and everybody (obviously) knew what moving is, so "Moving Pictures" communicated what a person would see far better than a more technical definition. It could easily be put on a sign or a caller could yell it out to attract curious passersby.

From there, slang took over and we got movie, film (from the medium), flick (from the flicker of early projectors), etc. etc. in different languages and dialects around the world.

Comment: Movies are still static images, the same thing with television and video, they're just a sequence of still images in rapid succession.

Comment: @AmberAlvia - except that they're not. A collection of things is not the same as a single thing. Moving pictures fit the mathematical set of [sets of still images], but not the set [still images] as they are not a single still image. Novels and sentences was a good analogy. Or letters and words. Or cars and traffic. Or atoms and people. Not that I'd trust atoms - they make up everything.

Comment: Novels are sentences are different, but again, Movies, TV shows and videos are made out of mathematical set of still images, every medium is made out of still images like drawings, paintings and photographs, People call it movies because of the optical illusion that the still images look like they're moving when they actually not.

Comment: @AmberAlvia - They're kind of moving - one moment they're there, the next they're not - but isn't "People call it movies because of the optical illusion that the still images look like they're moving when they actually not." the answer to your original question?

Answer (score 2):

They're different because the ***perception*** of the viewer to each is different. After all, the entire purpose of creating any type of image record, whether still or moving, is to recreate a visual perception of the thing(s) being imaged.

Still images are perceived as static. They're a *single moment frozen in time*. We can look at them for hours and hours and they will not change.

Moving pictures are perceived as kinetic. They're a *series of moments that show time progressing*. We can't even usually perceive a single frame within them as a single frame, we only perceive the changes that occur as frame after frame rushes past at 24, 30, 60 or more frames per second. The individual still frames that make up a motion picture are fleeting as they constantly change.

Comment: Moving pictures are not real movement or really kinetic, it's an illusion where your brain thinks the still images are moving, they're a sequence of still images one after the other, our eyes still register still images in movies, TV programs and videos.

Comment: @Amber One could equally ask the question "Why do they call it a sun rise? The sun doesn't rise. The earth rotates and it comes into view." Language is about encoding meaning, so in normal parlance, sometimes a description that lacks precision can be more accurate than a technically perfect answer.

Comment: Excellent answer, something else the OP could try is to look at each individual frame in a movie. The quality of each frame is generally (mostly?) substandard from a photographic perspective. But when watching the playback at full speed, the result is vastly superior than the sum of its parts. Consider how much emulated imperfection computer animators jam into images to make them look 'right' when they whizz by our eyes.

Comment: @AmberAlvia Thus the statement: "Moving pictures are *perceived* as kinetic" rather than "Moving pictures *are* kinetic." Our eyes do not register (perceive) anything. Our brains created a perception based on input from the eyes, but also on other influencing factors as well.

Comment: As I said before moving pictures are a optical illusion since they're not actually moving, have you looked at a YouTube video frame by frame or a clip of a movie or TV program frame by frame, if you play the still images in a rapid succession, then you're seeing still images at a sufficient speed that it looks like it's moving, Movies/TV program/videos are a optical illusion that our brains think that the still images are moving when they're not actually moving.

Comment: @Amber, nobody here is arguing the images are really moving. Everybody over the age of 4 knows that it is a sequence of images tricking their brains into seeing motion. But have you considered that the ***purpose*** of them ***is*** that illusion of motion? The illusion of motion is the defining difference between the two mediums. Nobody is lying when they say motion picture, they are describing it by its true purpose. Being succinct and being completely accurate are mutually exclusive goals. Let me issue you a challenge then: propose a perfectly accurate name in 3 words or less.

Comment: okay, I'm sorry about, We're not arguing the images are really moving, Everybody know that movies/TV programs/videos are a sequence of images tricking their brains into seeing motion, end of discussion.

Comment: @AmberAlvia Albert Einstein said, "Reality is merely an illusion, although a very persistent one."

Comment: @AmberAlvia "...have you looked at a YouTube video frame by frame or a clip of a movie or TV program frame by frame..." Sure. I've also held movies on actual film in my hands and looked at individual frames. What's your point? The purpose of putting those still images in sequence to be displayed at 24 fps is to create the *perception* of motion. End of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Reductionism

> ... is any of several related philosophical ideas regarding the associations between phenomena which can be described in terms of other simpler or more fundamental phenomena. It is also described as an intellectual and philosophical position that interprets a complex system as the sum of its parts.
>
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductionism)

Arguments about philosophy might be better suited to Philosophy StackExchange, there are already many [questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=reductionism) discussing the finer points of reductionsim.

Moving images are just a collection of images. Images are essentially just paintings, created in a different way. Paintings are just flat areas, with colors. Flat areas ...

Except that we reduce a complex system to one of its parts and forget about the others.

Of course, you can create moving images from a bunch of images. Not any random images, but images that are somehow related to each other, that tell some kind of story. Every parameter of a still image is dynamic now and might change over a sequence of images. You need to make up some new rules for that. And some rules of photography do no longer apply, e.g. some black or out-of-focus images are OK, now.

Then, you might want to add sound. If you want to do it right, you could even hire some people and have several minutes listing all kinds of professions at the end of your movie.